# Update não encontra o que foi digitado nos inputs

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, sql-update

Tenho um sistema onde você pode alterar as informações de um registro através de um formulário de edição, só que essa edição não está sendo salva.

**HTML**

```
<?php
                    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
                            mysqli_select_db($lnk,'banco') or die(mysql_error());

                    $query = mysqli_query($lnk, "SELECT PILOTE FROM qualite");
                    $kpi = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'KPI');
                    $pilote = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PILOTE');
                    $janPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JAN PREV');
                    $janReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JAN REAL');
                    $fevPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FEV PREV');
                    $fevReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FEV REAL');
                    $marPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAR PREV');
                    $marReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAR REAL');
                    $abrPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ABR PREV');
                    $abrReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ABR REAL');
                    $maiPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAI PREV');
                    $maiReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAI REAL');
                    $junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN PREV');
                    $junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN REAL');
                    $julPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUL PREV');
                    $julReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUL REAL');
                    $agoPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'AGO PREV');
                    $agoReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'AGO REAL');
                    $setPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SET PREV');
                    $setReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SET REAL');
                    $outPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'OUT PREV');
                    $outReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'OUT REAL');
                    $novPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'NOV PREV');
                    $novReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'NOV REAL');
                    $dezPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'DEZ PREV');
                    $dezReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'DEZ REAL');
                    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
                ?>
                    <form method="post" action="update-qualite.php">
                        <input name="ID" type="hidden" id="ID" value="<? echo $id; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>KPI</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="KPI" name="KPI" value="<?php echo $kpi; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>PILOTE</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PILOTE" name="PILOTE" value="<?php echo $pilote; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>JANEIRO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JAN PREV" name="JAN PREV" value="<?php echo $janPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>JANEIRO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JAN REAL" name="JAN REAL" value="<?php echo $janReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>FEVEREIRO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FEV PREV" name="FEV PREV" value="<?php echo $fevPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>FEVEREIRO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FEV REAL" name="FEV REAL" value="<?php echo $fevReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>MARÇO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MAR PREV" name="MAR PREV" value="<?php echo $marPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>MARÇO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MAR REAL" name="MAR REAL" value="<?php echo $marReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>ABRIL PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ABR PREV" name="ABR PREV" value="<?php echo $abrPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>ABRIL REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ABR REAL" name="ABR REAL" value="<?php echo $abrReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>MAIO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MAI PREV" name="MAI PREV" value="<?php echo $maiPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>MAIO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MAI REAL" name="MAI REAL" value="<?php echo $maiReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>JUNHO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JUN PREV" name="JUN PREV" value="<?php echo $junPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>JUNHO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JUN REAL" name="JUN REAL" value="<?php echo $junReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>JULHO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JUL PREV" name="JUL PREV" value="<?php echo $julPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>JULHO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JUL REAL" name="JUL REAL" value="<?php echo $julReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>AGOSTO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AGO PREV" name="AGO PREV" value="<?php echo $agoPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>AGOSTO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AGO REAL" name="AGO REAL" value="<?php echo $agoReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>SETEMBRO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SET PREV" name="SET PREV" value="<?php echo $setPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>SETEMBRO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SET REAL" name="SET REAL" value="<?php echo $setReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>OUTUBRO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="OUT PREV" name="OUT PREV" value="<?php echo $outPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>OUTUBRO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="OUT REAL" name="OUT REAL" value="<?php echo $outReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>NOVEMBRO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NOV PREV" name="NOV PREV" value="<?php echo $novPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>NOVEMBRO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NOV REAL" name="NOV REAL" value="<?php echo $novReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>DEZEMBRO PREVISTO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DEZ PREV" name="DEZ PREV" value="<?php echo $dezPrev; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <label>DEZEMBRO REALIZADO</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DEZ REAL" name="DEZ REAL" value="<?php echo $dezReal; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-theme btn-theme-sm btn-base-bg text-uppercase">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE-QUALITE.PHP**

```
<!--Update de edição-->
<?php

    $kpi = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'KPI');
    $pilote = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PILOTE');
    $janPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JAN PREV');
    $janReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JAN REAL');
    $fevPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FEV PREV');
    $fevReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FEV REAL');
    $marPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAR PREV');
    $marReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAR REAL');
    $abrPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ABR PREV');
    $abrReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ABR REAL');
    $maiPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAI PREV');
    $maiReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MAI REAL');
    $junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN PREV');
    $junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN REAL');
    $julPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUL PREV');
    $julReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUL REAL');
    $agoPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'AGO PREV');
    $agoReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'AGO REAL');
    $setPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SET PREV');
    $setReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SET REAL');
    $outPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'OUT PREV');
    $outReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'OUT REAL');
    $novPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'NOV PREV');
    $novReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'NOV REAL');
    $dezPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'DEZ PREV');
    $dezReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'DEZ REAL');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'banco') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "UPDATE  `banco`.`qualite` SET `KPI` = '$kpi', `PILOTE` = '$pilote', `JAN PREV` = '$janPrev', `JAN REAL` = '$janReal', `FEV PREV` = '$fevPrev', `FEV REAL` = '$fevReal', `MAR PREV` = '$marPrev', `MAR REAL` = '$marReal', `ABR PREV` = '$abrPrev', `ABR REAL` = '$abrReal', `MAI PREV` = '$maiPrev', `MAI REAL` = '$maiReal', `JUN PREV` = '$junPrev',
    `JUN REAL` = '$junReal', `JUL PREV` = '$julPrev', `JUL REAL` = '$julReal', `AGO PREV` = '$agoPrev', `AGO REAL` = '$agoReal', `SET PREV` = '$setPrev', `SET REAL` = '$setReal', `OUT PREV` = '$outPrev', `OUT REAL` = '$outReal', `NOV PREV` = '$novPrev', `NOV REAL` = '$novReal', `DEZ PREV` = '$dezPrev', `DEZ REAL` = '$dezReal' WHERE  `qualite`.`ID` = '$id'";

    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    var_dump($sql);


?>
```

Só que quando eu dou esse var_dump(), aparece o seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que já estava salvo no banco a variável tá até recebendo, mas o que eu to tentando alterar não tá recebendo.

**EDIT: COLOQUEI UM CAMPO HIDDEN COM O ID NO INÍCIO DO FORMULÁRIO E AGORA ELE PEGA O ID, MAS O RESTO AINDA NÃO.**

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: no update tem WHERE  `qualite`.`ID` = '$id'" Só que no formulário não está passando o valor `$id`

Comment: Então, criei um campo hidden para o ID no início do formulário e agora ele reconhece o ID, mas o resto ainda não.

Answer (score 1):

Quando um `name` de algum elemento do formulário contem espaço,  e o formulário é submetido, a página que vai recuperar o valor desse elemento substitui o espaço por um underscore (_), conhecido também por traço rasteiro, underline ou traço inferior ou linha baixa. Portanto ao recuperar os valores dos campos submetidos substitua o espaço por um `underline`

Exemplo:

```
no formulario <input name="JAN PREV" .....

para recuperar o valor desse input `$janPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JAN_PREV');`
```

**Se você rodar algo como**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="JAN PREV" name="JAN PREV" value="xxx">
    <input type="text" id="JAN REAL" name="JAN REAL" value="zzz">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
       echo $name." ". $value;
       echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**o resultado vai ser**

```
JAN_PREV xxx
JAN_REAL zzz
```

---

---

**Observações**

Você está sobrescrevendo a variável `$junReal` ao invés de criar 2 variáveis `$junPrev` e `$junReal`

```
..............
$junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN PREV');
$junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN REAL');
..............
```

Correção:

```
..............
$junPrev = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN PREV');
$junReal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'JUN REAL');
..............
```

> no update tem `WHERE`qualite`.`ID`= '$id'` Só que no formulário não está passando o valor $id

1. O seu formulário não está trazendo os dados do banco para colocar nos inputs.
2. O seu SELECT `$query = mysqli_query($lnk, "SELECT PILOTE FROM qualite");` só está trazendo o valor do campo `PILOTE`

   ```
   Coloque um * ou o nome das colunas necessárias
   ```
3. Essas linhas

   ```
     $kpi = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'KPI'); 
     $pilote = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PILOTE');
     ............................................
     etc.....`
   ```

   Não servem para nada na página do formulário

> Para trazer dados do banco

```
 $query = mysqli_query($lnk, "SELECT * FROM qualite");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $kpi = $row["KPI"];
        $pilote = $row["PILOTE"];
        $janPrev = $row["JAN PREV"];
        $janReal = $row["JAN REAL"];
        ...........................
        ...........................

    }
```

Comment: Obrigada pela correção. Eu editei aqui mas ainda tá dando o mesmo problema. :/

Comment: Então, eu coloquei um campo hidden no formulário com o ID. Vou editar ali em cima

Comment: https://ideone.com/SnpVgd

Comment: Eu não to entendendo porque o seu tá funcionando perfeitinho e o meu não. Até cheguei a colar o seu $sql aqui e não tá funcionando. :/

Comment: É esquisito porque ele chega a pegar as coisas que já estavam salvas no banco, que no caso são KPI e PILOTE, mas o resto não.

Comment: O que você alterou pro código funcionar?

Comment: Só coloquei o _ e funcionou. Obrigada. Comenta com resposta pra eu dar como respondido.